# Python - Which parameters for inner class?

Tags: python, class, inner-classes

I'm currently testing the classes in Python. When I try to use inner classes, I don't really know which parameters I should use for them in other classes.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, r, ???):
        self.rayon = r
        self.centre = self.Point()
```

In this part of the code, I put extra parameters for the **init** but I really don't know which parameters I should use for the self.centre in Circle class, considering that centre is a Point object.

Thank you !

Comment: I don't see an inner-class here. Are you sure, the indentation is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter a whole lot whether you wish to pass an extra `(x,y)`, or a whole `Point` class.   Point is not a member variable of Circle, so the code needs `self.centre = Point(...)`, and not `self.centre = self.point(...) #WRONG!`

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __str__(self):
        return "(%d,%d)" % (self.x, self.y)

class CircleA:
    def __init__(self, r, x, y):
        self.radius = r
        self.centre = Point( x, y )
    def __str__(self):
        return "CircleA at %s, radius=%d" % (str(self.centre),self.radius)

class CircleB:
    def __init__(self, r, p):
        self.radius = r
        self.centre = p

    def __str__(self):
        return "CircleB at %s, radius=%d" % (str(self.centre),self.radius)
```

But the creation of the object must be different, to match:

```
circle1 = CircleA( 10, 0, 0 )
print("circle1 is " + str(circle1))

circle2 = CircleB( 10, Point( 0, 0) )
print("circle2 is " + str(circle2))
```

Giving:

```
python3 ./circle.py 
circle1 is CircleA at (0,0), radius=10
circle2 is CircleB at (0,0), radius=10
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are initializing a `Point` inside `Circle`, then pass the same params `x` and `y` to the `Circle` class like so:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, r, x, y):
        self.rayon = r
        self.centre = Point(x, y)
```

Then, `Point` will take those `x` and `y` params when it goes through `__init__` upon instantiation

If you don't give it anything, like `Point()`, it will throw an Error saying that you don't have required positional args `x` and `y`. Also, note that I have dropped `self` from `Point`, as `self.Point` hasn't been defined in `Circle`